# How to use the same date picker in different screens?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to use the same a function that picks the date and the time in multiple screens, is it possible to do so?

I cannot extract showDatePicker because it is not a widget.

this is the method I am trying to call in multiple screens
Is there another way of copying the code into the different screens? I suppose that is not an effective way of doing that where if I change something, I would have to change it in all different places.

```
Future<void> _selectDateTime() async {
    final pickedDate = await showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: pickedDate,
      firstDate: DateTime(2021),
      lastDate: DateTime(2100),
      builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
        return Theme(
          data: ThemeData.light().copyWith(
            colorScheme: ColorScheme.light(
              primary: yellowLight,
              onPrimary: Colors.white,
              onSurface: blackTitle,
            ),
          ),
          child: child,
        );
      },
    );

    final pickedTime = await showTimePicker(
      context: context,
      initialTime: TimeOfDay.now(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
        return Theme(
          data: ThemeData.light().copyWith(
            colorScheme: ColorScheme.light(
              primary: yellowLight,
              onPrimary: Colors.white,
              onSurface: blackTitle,
            ),
          ),
          child: child,
        );
      },
    );
    setState(() {
      //do something
    });

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your method to something like this:

```dart
Future<DateTime> _selectDateTime(BuildContext context) async {
  return showDatePicker(
    context: context,
    // ... other properties.
  );
}
```

And you can then use it in Screen-1:

```dart
void someMethod() async {
  final dateTime = await _selectDateTime(context);
}
```

And in Screen-2:

```dart
void someMethod2() async {
  final dateTime = await _selectDateTime(context);
}
```